# Why do I have an error "default.initializeApp(...).auth is not a function" using firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

So I'm creating a react app using firebase and my `firebase.js` file looks like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/auth";
export const auth = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "{my_key}",
    authDomain: "{domain}",
    projectId: "{project_id}",
    storageBucket: "{storage}",
    messagingSenderId: "{sender_id}",
    appId: "{app_id}",
    measurementId: "{blablabla}"
  }).auth();
```

And my `Login.jsx`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

import { auth } from '../firebase';

<Button onClick={() => auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())}>
```

I want to sign in through google, as you can see, so I import `auth` from `firebase.js`, but when I do `npm start` I have the next error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.initializeApp(...).auth is not a function

I'm not sure why it says that `auth` is not a function.

Edit:
I also tried to import with `require('firebase/auth')` but it didn't help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hi! i tried and it says `export 'default' (imported as 'auth') was not found in '../firebase'`

Comment: kk, it was worth a shot as I sometimes lose track of import variatns these days. Cleaning up comments in that case to that other's are more likely to chime in.